# Can I install / downgrade to Mojave on a new MacBook Pro 2020 that comes with Catalina?

Tags: macos, time-machine, mojave, catalina

I'm planning on buying a new 16-inch MacBook Pro. However, it will come with Catalina, and I still rely on several 32-bit apps. I was wondering if it's possible to downgrade to Mojave?

I was thinking maybe through a Time Machine backup... I've restored from Time Machine before to downgrade from High Sierra to Sierra. Would it be possible to set up the new computer from a Time Machine backup with Mojave?

I'm worried the new hardware would not accept an older OS...

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you please specify exactly which model of MacBook Pro are you planning to buy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing, all the models of MacBook Pro lineup available for purchase currently from Apple or any 3rd party resellers (13" or 15") can be downgraded to run macOS Mojave 10.14.5 or a later release, **except** the 16" MacBook Pro which **cannot be** downgraded to run macOS Mojave.

**P.S.**: No new MacBook Pro model has been released in the year 2020 so far (as of this writing). So there's no 2020 MacBook Pro yet. So essentially what you can get is either a Late 2019 16" MacBook Pro or a Mid 2019 13" or 15" model (assuming you are purchasing a brand new one, and if some resellers are still selling the discontinued but last released 15" ones)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why 13" & 15" can be downgraded, but not 16"?

Comment: @LNah The reason is whether the model was released before Catalina. If it shipped with Mojave or older, it would be able to run something before Catalina...